# F# exception error when defining pattern matching function with lists of tuples

Tags: f#

I'd like to create a function that compares 2 lists of tuples and returns tuple elements that match in both lists.

So far I have defined my function like this:

```
let rec matchNames l1 l2  = 
    match (l1,l2) with
    | (n1,_,_) :: l1' , (n2,_,_)  :: l2' when n1 = n2 -> n1 :: matchNames l1' l2' 
    | _,_ -> failwith "error"
```

Suppose I have 2 lists:

```
let l1 = [("Name1",1,2);("Name2",2,2)]
let l2 = [("Name2",3,2);("Name1",1,2);("Name3",1,1)]
```

When I apply these lists to my function it triggers my failwith exception:

```
System.Exception: error
  at FSI_0457.matchNames[0,1,2,3,4] (Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] l1, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] l2) [0x000b7] in <f035af7fb206481ab722b92b2672833a>:0 
  at <StartupCode$FSI_0458>.$FSI_0458.main@ () [0x0000a] in <f035af7fb206481ab722b92b2672833a>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <b18e5763ec3f41e68a8fe16d7f5e0bee>:0 
Stopped due to error
```

So obviously my exception isn't defined properly. Any suggestions or references on how to define is appreciated.

Just in case, the expected outcome of  *matchNames l1 l2* should be:

```
["Name1";"Name2"]
```

Comment: Why do you have `failwith "error"` there at all? In which circumstances is that the desired outcome? I suspect this is [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and that the actual problem is the error you get if you remove that line.

Comment: Why would "Name1" be in the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in defining l2

Comment: glennsl - if I don't use failwith "error" then I get "Incomplete pattern matches on this expression." error.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Why have you replaced a meaningful error message with one that is not, and then ask about the latter?

Comment: As you mentioned, it was a XY problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out almost acceptable answer:

```
let rec matchNames l1 l2  = 
    match (l1,l2) with
    | (n1,_,_) :: l1' , (n2,_,_)  :: l2' when n1 = n2 -> n1 :: matchNames l1' l2' 
    | (n1,_,_) :: l1' , (n2,_,_)  :: l2' when n1 <> n2 -> []
    | _,_ -> []
```

By almost, is that function matches only these names if they are at the same index at both lists.

For example:

```
let l1 = [("Name1",1,2);("Name2",2,2)]
let l2 = [("Name2",3,2);("Name1",1,2);("Name3",1,1)]

matchNames l1 l2
```

Has an output of empty list

But if I define l1 and l2 accordingly

```
let l1 = [("Name1",1,2);("Name2",2,2)]
let l2 = [("Name1",3,2);("Name2",1,2);("Name3",1,1)]
```

It's not perfect but works for now, if someone has a solution which does not depend on matching list indexes then it would be appreciated if you post it here. :)

Comment: Recursing only when you match means you'll never process beyond the first non-match. Advancing the "head" you're looking at only in the case of a match means you'll never compare elements non-positially. A list is a poor data structure for this operation, but your algorithm isn't doing what your problem statement says you want, which is "find all elements which exist in both lists".